# swap function using memcpy and void*

Tags: c, memcpy, void-pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void swap (void *vp1, void *vp2, const size_t size) {
    char *buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
    memcpy(buffer, vp1, size);
    memcpy(vp1, vp2, size);
    memcpy(vp2, buffer, size);
    free(buffer);
}

int main()
{
    char *puppy = strdup("Wow");
    char *kitty = strdup("Mew");

    printf("%s, %s\n", puppy, kitty);
    swap(&puppy, &kitty, sizeof(char **));
    printf("%s, %s\n", puppy, kitty);

    free(puppy);
    free(kitty);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to make practise to understand using `void*` and `memcpy()`. In this code at first I thought `swap(puppy, kitty, sizeof(char *));` It works. But I don't understand the usage `swap(&puppy, &kitty, sizeof(char **));` Could someone explain how the second swap works?

Comment: Should `const int size` be `const size_t size`?

Comment: Neither of the two are correct.

Comment: @user3528438 - What do you suggest?

Comment: The first case only works when your machine has a pointer of the same size of your string, which is true for x86-64 in this case because the pointer is 4x size of char and your string has 4 chars including the terminater. The second case only works when char * has the same size as char **, which is usually true for all machines.

Comment: I think it's not problem. Isn't it ? but I've changed @EdHeal

Comment: sizeof void probably must be strlen

Comment: In the first case, you are swapping the contents of the string, so it requires both operands being of the same length, so use `swap(puppy, kitty, 4);`. The second case is switching the value of the pointer, or, where the pointers points to, so should be `swap(&puppy, &kitty, sizeof(char *));`

Comment: Don't cast `malloc` in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the following two lines:

```
char *puppy = strdup("Wow");
char *kitty = strdup("Mew");
```

The memory usage looks something like this:

```
puppy
+-----------+      +---+---+---+-----+
| address1  |  ->  | W | o | w | \0  |
+-----------+      +---+---+---+-----+

kitty
+-----------+      +---+---+---+-----+
| address2  |  ->  | M | e | w | \0  |
+-----------+      +---+---+---+-----+
```

You can implement swap couple of ways:

Swap Method 1: Change the values of pointers.

```
puppy
+-----------+      +---+---+---+-----+
| address2  |  ->  | M | e | w | \0  |
+-----------+      +---+---+---+-----+

kitty
+-----------+      +---+---+---+-----+
| address1  |  ->  | W | o | w | \0  |
+-----------+      +---+---+---+-----+
```

Swap Method 2: Change the contents of what the pointers point to:

```
puppy
+-----------+      +---+---+---+-----+
| address1  |  ->  | M | e | w | \0  |
+-----------+      +---+---+---+-----+

kitty
+-----------+      +---+---+---+-----+
| address2  |  ->  | W | o | w | \0  |
+-----------+      +---+---+---+-----+
```

If you want the behavior of the first approach, you need to use:

```
swap(&puppy, &kitty, sizeof(char*));
```

If you want behavior of the second approach, you need to use:

```
swap(puppy, kitty, strlen(puppy));
```

Keep in mind that the second approach will be a problem if the strings are of different lengths.

Comment: `swap(&puppy, &kitty, sizeof(char*));` or `swap(&puppy, &kitty, sizeof(char**));` ?

Comment: `sizeof(char*)` is right since you are swapping one `char*` object.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom, that's what I meant. I was hoping that was clear.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom, Is there a better ASCII art to indicate that `address1` is the value of `puppy`?